# Moving A Mapkit Annotation 10m?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, mapkit

ive been programming through XCode, and am making use of the MapKit API. Bit confused though, if I wanted to move an annotation by 10 metres, how would I do this? I assume its possible since you can display to nearest 10m. Thanks!

Comment: You just need to get the coordinate of the new location 10 meters away, remove the current annotation, then place a new annotation at your new location.  Is what your asking how to get the location 10 meters away?

Comment: See to [1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1322537/5593725)  [2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2795209/5593725) and [3](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5191125/5593725) for help to Annoation

Comment: Sorry i forgot my acc detaols. But yeah, thats what Im asking. How would i move a co ordiante by 10m? I know it sounds stupid, but stuff like this confuses